# how to categorize a column and put in a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe where the `type` columns shows the type of a stuff

```
id    type     total
1     shoes      2
1     sandal     1
1     vest       2
1     tshirt     2
1     345        3
1     345        2
```

based on the `type` column, I want to categorize the type and create a new column called `category`.
The rules are as follow:

```
- shoes and sandal as shoes
- vest, we keep it as vest
- tshirt, we also keep it as tshirt
- other than that, I want to keep it as other
```

so the desired result will be as follow:

```
id    type     total    category
1     shoes      2       shoes
1     sandal     1       shoes
1     vest       2       vest
1     tshirt     2       tshirt
1     345        3       other
1     345        2       other
```

how can I make it with python?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) on a dictionary with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.Series.fillna):

```
>>> df['category'] = df['type'].map({'sandal': 'shoes', 'shoes': 'shoes', 'vest': 'vest', 'tshirt': 'tshirt'}).fillna('other')
>>> df
   id    type  total category
0   1   shoes      2    shoes
1   1  sandal      1    shoes
2   1    vest      2     vest
3   1  tshirt      2   tshirt
4   1     345      3    other
5   1     345      2    other
>>>
```

As mentioned in the documentation of both pages (links shown above), `map` maps and replaces the values in the `Series` that are the keys of the dictionary to the values of the dictionary. Whereas if there are values in there series that aren't mapped in the dictionary, it would give `NaN`s, so you could just do `fillna` to replace the `NaN`s with `others`.